# how to add something on same line?

Tags: html, css

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

nav {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <img src="image.png" alt="Logo" />
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

I want to add some element (like div tag) on the same line, within **header** tag but I can not because **div** tag takes full width. But as I guessed div is not a reason, `display: flex` doesn't let me add something to the same line.

Comment: have you tried `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell1,
.cell2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

nav {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell1">
      <img src="image.png" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell2">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi Anil, welcome to StackOverflow. It would really help if you added some explanation to your answers, to help people understand how and why your solution works, so that they can learn from it! Thanks, happy answering!

Answer (score 0):

since you want the `div` to have a "sibling", you need to move `display: flex;` to the parent element, which in your case is the header. Then declare how much `flex` you want for each child.

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="left">
    <img src="image.png" alt="Logo"/>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://google.com">Google</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="right">hello</div>
  </header>
</body>
```

-

```
header{
  background-color:red;
  border:5px solid green;
  display:flex;
}

div{
  border:2px solid blue;
  height: 200px;
  width:50%;
  align-items: center;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
}
```